# Split URL to set cookie using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Hoping you can help. I think I'm nearly there but my code has a slight error in it. I'm trying to set a cookie which sets the cookie value based on a section of the page url.

For example my cookie name is "model" and my cookie value is populated based on the url

https://www.website.co.uk/cars/100sr/

in the example above the cookie value should be set as 100sr

However, I've just noticed an error, where if the customer visits my website with a query string on the url, it's setting the cookie value to the query string content not the 100sr

e.g.

https://www.website.co.uk/cars/100sr/?testing

the url above using my current code would set the cookie as ?testing when I want it to still be set as 100sr. I'm guessing my code is taking the content after the LAST / is there perhaps a way to specify to take the content after the 2nd / instead?

Code below

```
<script>$("#carbtn").bind("click", function() {
  const strings = window.location.href.split("/").filter(str => !!str);
  document.cookie=`model=${strings[strings.length - 1]};path=/;`
});</script>
```

Comment: `strings[1]`? I'd probably put some checking in there around `strings.length >= 2`, but that's me. I'd also use `on` instead of `bind`, which has been deprecated for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `pathname` instead of the `href`, you'll be able to retrieve the portion of the URL without the query string. For example, on the URL:

[Split URL to set cookie using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67402851/split-url-to-set-cookie-using-javascript?foobar=abc)

Using `window.location.pathname` returns:

```
"/questions/67402851/split-url-to-set-cookie-using-javascript"
```

So do:

```
$("#carbtn").bind("click", function() {
  const strings = window.location.pathname.split("/").filter(str => !!str);
  document.cookie = `model=${strings[strings.length - 1]};path=/;`
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>$("#carbtn").bind("click", function() {
  const strings = window.location.href.split("/").filter(str => !!str);
  document.cookie=`model=${strings[strings.length - 1]};path=/;`
});</script>
```

This code gets the last element on the split of "/", so "/my/path/" gets the empty string after "path/[HERE]", you might need to dig into the awful (or wonderful) world of regexp for that

```
const lastItemOnURL = window.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+\/?$/);
if (lastItemOnURL[0]) { document.cookie = `model=${lastItemOnURL[0].replace('/', '')};path=/;` }
```

Notice that window.location.pathname doesn't grab the eventual ?get=values in the URL so you probably need that too